# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout cant collapse when recyclerView it's not visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've a CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout everything works at it should when in portrait mode because my recyclerView it's visible and i can collpase the toolbar by dragging the recyclerView, but when the recyclerView it's not visible i cant collpase the toolbar.

my xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image_adega"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/list_wines_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_wines"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Portrait - RecyclerView visible - can drag can collapse**
[image: can collapse]

**Landscape - RecyclerView not visible - can't drag can't collapse**
[image: can't collapse]

PS: I've updated to all support and design libs to 23.0.1 and it's the same result

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Support Library 23.1

> You’ll also find that AppBarLayout now allows users to start scrolling from within the AppBarLayout rather than only from within your scrollable view - this behavior can be controlled by adding a [DragCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback.html?utm_campaign=android_update_important_bug_fixes_101515&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=blog)

Comment: Yes I've saw the updated library and this was fixed in the 23.1

Answer (score 1):

> I've a CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout
>   everything works at it should when in portrait mode because my
>   recyclerView it's visible and i can collpase the toolbar by dragging
>   the recyclerView, but when the recyclerView it's not visible i cant
>   collpase the toolbar.
>   Blockquote

In Landscape mode, you are not able to collapse the toolbar because you are not having any scrollable content in your view such like RecyclerView.

This also should be the expected behavior. Regarding your concern about landscape mode, I would recommend you to re-think about landscape mode design and make it such that your AppBar contains 60-70% height of your device and rest of them should contain your Scrollable view. you can take Playstore app for your reference.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That was what i was thinking. so it's the expected behavior, in my mind i expected the toolbar to be also considered scrollable content.

Comment: can you give the link to some kind of documentation about this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some digging and try and error i found this is know bug still present in 23 versions. [code google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176673&q=collapsingToolbarLayout%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)